# Out of Memory Exception when handling large files in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, list

I have a C# winforms application, wherein I use an 
   OpenFileDialog to let the users choose text files to open.(Multiple Selection allowed)
Once they select the text files, I open the files one by one, get the text and store the contents in a List variable by using the List.Add() operation.

My problem occurs when the user selects an unusually large amount of text files like 1264 text files total size up to 750MB, the program is unable to handle it. It reads up to some 850 files then gives me an out of memory exception.
In task manager my application's memory(private working set) is around 1.5GB when this occurs.
I use x64 machine with 32GB ram.

I am giving the code which reads through the files:

```
public static List<LoadData> LoadDataFromFile(string[] filenames)
{
    List<LoadData> MasterData = new List<LoadData>();
    lookingForJobs = new LookingForJobs(1,filenames.Length);
    lookingForJobs.Show();
    /*-------OUTER LOOP TO GO THROUGH ALL THE FILES-------*/
    for (int index = 0; index < filenames.Length; index++)
    {
        string path = filenames[index];
        /*----------INNER LOOP TO GO THROUGH THE CONTENTS OF EACH FILE------*/
        foreach (string line in File.ReadAllLines(path))
        {
            string[] columns = line.Split('\t');
            if (columns.Length == 9)
            {
                if (line.StartsWith("<"))    /*-------IGNORING THE FIRST 8 LINES OF EACH LOG FILE CONTAINING THE LOGGER INFO---------*/
                {
                    MasterData.Add(new LoadData
                    {
                        Event_Type = columns[0],
                        Timestamp = columns[1],
                        Log_Message = columns[2],
                        Category = columns[3],
                        User = columns[4],
                        Thread_ID = columns[5],
                        Error_Code = columns[6],
                        Application = columns[7],
                        Machine = columns[8]
                    });
                }
            }
        }
        lookingForJobs.SearchingForJobsProgress.PerformStep();
        /*--------END OF INNER LOOP--------*/
    }
    lookingForJobs.Dispose();
    /*-----------END OF OUTER LOOP-----*/
    return MasterData;
}
```

Edit:
I understand that I should possibly redesign my code so that not all the files are read into the object at once. But, I want to know if there is any limit to the size of the list object or the memory(private working set). I read in a few articles that sometime when you hit 1.5-1.6 GB these kinds of problems occur.

Comment: Are you building the application in x64 mode?

Comment: @Guffa adding memory until it bursts is not *necessarily* the right "fix" here, especially when the streamed (instead of buffered) approach is so trivial (see Konrad's answer)

Comment: Are you sure you need all of that data in memory at once ... ?

Comment: @MarcGravell: As that data is thrown away after each file is processed, I can't image that it would make such a big difference.

Comment: @Simon, yeah maybe I can go for an approach which deletes some data after I process it. My MasterData list size comes upto ~2564543 elements. Is there any limit here?

Comment: @Guffa, Garbage Collection is not a magic, you can saturate memory even with little data if produced extremely fast. Nevertheless it seems to be not the case here.

Comment: Ok, so given that streaming the data still has it running out of memory, it seems likely that `MasterData` is getting huge - which means that @Guffa's first question seems a good one.

Comment: You could size each of the column strings explicitly when you assign them to your MasterData class. By default a string will allocate ~80 bytes regardless of what you put in it. You could easily save 75% of the space that way dependent on what your string values are.

Comment: Okay, so I was building the application in x86 mode. I tried in x64 mode and it worked fine!!!! I am sorry for not including the mode which I built it in. But thanks all of you for your insight. I learned that I have to do a bit of redesign anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your files might be small, but that MasterData object you're building will still be storing all the data it finds in memory...

Sounds like you might have a bit of application redesign to do...

Have you ran this through a profiler - see if you can examine memory usage throughout the course of your program?

Comment: At least two possibilities: (1) Use x64 (assuming the number of individual elements does not exceed 2^31) or (2) write the `MasterData` data out to a file, and process it later a record at a time.

Answer (score 7):

Use `File.ReadLines` instead of `File.ReadAllLines` as the second is unnecessarily loading all file into memory, while you need only one line at once. [MSDN says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/dd383503%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> When you use ReadAllLines, you must wait for the whole array of strings be returned before you can access the array. Therefore, when you are working with very large files, ReadLines can be more efficient.

This will give you probably quite big memory improvement.

The second thought is to rethink if you really need so big data stored in memory. Maybe you may just store filepath to each file and read them at demand.

Comment: Sometimes, a trivial-looking change is so startlingly effective.

Comment: Yeah, I changed it and the same problem occurs. The individual files are not very large(~650KB per file).

Comment: As that data is thrown away after each file is processed, it won't make a big difference.

Comment: @KonradKokosa: All the string objects have to be created for either solution, so there will not be a big difference from a memory management view.

Answer (score 2):

You are creating objects that contain most of the data that you read from the files. I think that the values for category, user, error code, application and machine would be repeated for a lot of records.

You could make a dictionary that contains those string values. For each value that you read, you would check if an equal string already exist in the dictionary and use that instead, otherwise add it. That way those strings would only exist once in memory.

String interning uses the same principle, but it you intern the strings they will stay in memory until the application is closed. By putting them in a dictionary you are able to let them be removed when you don't need them any more.

Example; make a dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, string> values = new Dictionary<string, string>();
```

Get a value and use/register a value in the dictionary:

```
string category = columns[3];
if (values.ContainsKey(category)) {
  category = values[category];
} else {
  values.Add(category, category);
}
```

You would of course only use this on the values where you expect to have a lot of repeated values.

Comment: This is an interesting optimization I never thought of. Would greatly reduce the memory if implemented. Thanks!